# Get list of circles of a user using Google Plus API

Tags: javascript, android, google-api, titanium, google-oauth

I am using google aouth with following in scope

```
scope : ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read']
```

I tried to get information about user, I've used following API

```
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
            onload : function() {
                var data = this.responseText;
                var json = JSON.parse(data);
                Ti.API.log('json: ' + JSON.stringify(json));
            }
        });
        xhr.open("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=" + googleAuth.getAccessToken());
        xhr.send();
```

but it only gives information about users basic info, how can I get information about users friends in circle.

I replaced `xhr.open("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=" + googleAuth.getAccessToken());` with

```
xhr.open("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/me/circles?access_token=" + googleAuth.getAccessToken());
```

the responce text in console was like

```
json: {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"forbidden","message":"Forbidden"}],"code":403,"message":"Forbidden"}}
```

I have enabled

- Google+ API,
- Blogger API,
- Google+ Pages API,
- Google+ Domains API,

Comment: I dont think you can get it for a user.  https://developers.google.com/+/domains/ is not the same as  https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/

Comment: @DaImTo Here user is me, I want to get my own circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to this that the API has is [People.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/connected?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Try testing the collection see which one suits your needs more.   You can test the results at the bottom of the page.  There is no way to get the name of the circle back.

> Acceptable values are:
>
> "connected": The list of visible people in the authenticated user's
>   circles who also use the requesting app. This list is limited to users
>   who made their app activities visible to the authenticated user.
>
> "visible": The list of people who this user has added to one or more
>   circles, limited to the circles visible to the requesting application.

Answer (score 0):

As of August 2018 the Google+ API endpoint `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/userId/people/collection` [is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/list).

[There is a new endpoint](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list) for getting all the contacts: `https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections`.
There is a `metadata` key in the response, and for Google+ contacts it will look somewhat like this:

```
  "metadata": {
    "sources": [
      {
        "updateTime": "2013-01-13T19:16:50.668Z", 
        "etag": "...", 
        "type": "CONTACT", 
        "id": "..."
      }, 
      {
        "etag": "...", 
        "type": "PROFILE", 
        "id": "...", 
        "profileMetadata": {
          "userTypes": [
            "GOOGLE_USER", 
            "GPLUS_USER"
          ], 
          "objectType": "PERSON"
        }
      }
    ], 
    "objectType": "PERSON"
  }
```

Note the `"GPLUS_USER"` part.