# Is it necessary to use google apps account to use Google+ Domain API's?

Tags: javascript, ios, google-api, google-plus, google-oauth

I am trying to get user's circle info with following api call

```
xhr.open("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/me/circles?alt=json&access_token=" + googleAuth.getAccessToken());
```

It gives response text as

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"forbidden","message":"Forbidden"}],"code":403,"message":"Forbidden"}}
```

I have enable google+ domain api

Comment: Forbidden means you don't have permissions to access that.

Comment: @DaImTo how to get permissions, I have written following lines in scope   scope : ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, [Google+ Domains API](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/) methods are not available to `@gmail.com` Google accounts. They require Google Apps accounts.

Answer (score 2):

The Google+ Domain API's is not the same as the Google+ API.

Your question says you are trying to find a `user circle` the Google+ API doesn't give you this information exactly.

The closes thing to this that the API has is [People.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/connected?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Try testing the collection see which one suits your needs more.  They each give you back a list of people.  You can test the results at the bottom of the page.  There is no way to get the name of the circle back.

> Acceptable values are:
>
> "connected": The list of visible people in the authenticated user's
>   circles who also use the requesting app. This list is limited to users
>   who made their app activities visible to the authenticated user.
>
> "visible": The list of people who this user has added to one or more
>   circles, limited to the circles visible to the requesting application.

This question is probably related to the one you posted yesterday.  [Get list of circles of a user using Google Plus API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674435/get-list-of-circles-of-a-user-using-google-plus-api)