# Google+ Domains API Not Configured

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

When I try to post an activity to Google+ I get the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403, 
    "message": "Access Not Configured. The API (Google+ Domains API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.", 
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "usageLimits", 
        "message": "Access Not Configured. The API (Google+ Domains API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.", 
        "reason": "accessNotConfigured", 
        "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I know this question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693375/is-it-necessary-to-use-google-apps-account-to-use-google-domain-apis), but I have a different message in my error. I've also enabled Google Domains API in the console. I'm using a Gmail account and I also receive circles and contacts information with the following scopes:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me

My Post body is:

```
{
"object": {
    "originalContent": "Happy Monday! #caseofthemondays"
},
"access": {
    "items": [
        {
            "type": "domain"
        }
    ],
    "domainRestricted": true
}
```

}

Comment: Was it working for you earlier?

Comment: For post operations you might need access token which was granted/provided by the user

Comment: I already have the token, that's how I'm getting other information.

Comment: I haven't used post operations in Google+. But in Facebook, we need a Facebook app to request the user to grant relevant post access and once user grant the access, an access token will be generated. You have to store it to use it later when you do post operations on behalf of the user.

Comment: Tokens for get and post are different (like read privilege and write privilege)

Comment: Yes. I can do the same thing for Facebook. But I think there's something wrong with this feature in Google, or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Your error domains indicate its a usage limit error. There are quota limits for each google API. So there is also a possibility that you might have fully used your free quota limits.

Comment: The quota is 10,000 requests/day  and I haven't used a single request yet

Comment: Did you try regenerating a new API key?

Comment: No. I'm using Google OAuth Playground to test it. It provides the information automatically.

Comment: So have followed the steps on this link? https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/creating

Comment: Hmmm...give me some time..

Comment: I will try and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out this feature is only available for Google Apps customers not anyone else.
[Reference](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you created (or using) the API_KEYs in your Google project?
If not, go to Google developer console and select the credentials section under APIs & Auth and create the API key relevant for your application.
If you already have a key, try regenerating a new one

Comment: I've created them once and I'm already able to receive contacts and google+ contacts of  the logged in user. Do I need another Key?

Comment: It's working with Google Contacts and Google+ Contacts. But I want to post to the user's google+. That's my problem

Comment: Sorry, I didn't try completely...
Did you follow [these](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/quickstart/java) steps?

Comment: I've posted an answer here. Only Google Apps members have access over Google+ Domain API, which allows you to post to a user's stream.

Comment: Is they clearly mention like that? I don't think so.  But if you are sure about that, it is a good finding.

Comment: "With the Google+ Domains API, Google Apps customers and ISVs can build custom Google+ functionality and services for people who use Google Apps ..."

Comment: sounds promising.. :)